# Cat is trying to get into the apartment every time we open the door

Tags: cats, behavior

There is a stray cat that lives near my building, I have spent time with her before. One day, I found the cat at my door scratching it and meowing.

As soon as we try to open the door, the cat tries to get inside. One time, she managed to get inside, she walked inside for sometime, then I managed to guide her outside. But she keep coming back every now and then to the door, scratching it and meowing.

I can't adopt the cat and we don't have shelters in here. I just want to convince her not to try to get inside. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot give the cat a home, the best thing that you can do is to ignore it. That means no feeding and no petting. The cat will soon get the message and look elsewhere for food and shelter. Giving the animal a mixed message (i.e. I love you but I'm not going to look after you) is confusing, and ultimately, cruel.

I speak as someone who did take in a stray cat, but then I was able to provide for his needs (and I love him very much). Unfortunately, a second cat came calling at my door, begging for food. Since I was unable to take on another cat, I simply had to ignore it. Eventually, it went away, and I haven't seen it for some time. Hopefully, it found a home (although there is the possibility that it was not a stray).